# How to make a function that is a friend of 2 classes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend

This is a grossly simplified version of what I am doing but gets the point across.  I have 2 classes that can be used for arithmetic.  My problem is I want to be able to multiply the 2 together but anyway I try this seems to cause a problem.  For example:

```
class A {
    uint32_t val_;

    A(uint32_t src) {
        val_=src;
    }
    friend A operator* (const A &a,const B &b); // <------ throws Unknown type B
};

class B {
    uint32_t val_;
    bool invert_;

    B(A src,bool invert) {
        val_=src.val_;
        invert_=invert;
    }
    friend A operator* (const A &a,const B &b);
};

A operator* (const A &a,const B &b) {
    if (b.invert_) return a.val_/b.val_;
    return a.val_*b.val_;
}
```

how can I get around this seeming recursive error?  If it wasn't for the B value always comes second I would put `A operator* (const A &a);` in the B class so I can just use `friend class B` in the A class

Comment: Did you try adding a forward declaration?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is I didn't know the term forward declaration.

```
class B;  //forward declare B

class A {
    uint32_t val_;

    A(uint32_t src) {
        val_=src;
    }
    friend A operator* (const A &a,const B &b);
};

class B {
    uint32_t val_;
    bool invert_;

    B(A src,bool invert) {
        val_=src.val_;
        invert_=invert;
    }
    friend A operator* (const A &a,const B &b);
};

A operator* (const A &a,const B &b) {
    if (b.invert_) return a.val_/b.val_;
    return a.val_*b.val_;
}
```

simple fix when you know the term.